# ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv and vgdisplay give different sizes for different commands

Tags: partitioning, disk, lvm

Even though the disk size is  221.57 GiB and there is no unallocated disk space and /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv gives only 98G where did the rest go?

output of:
`fdisk -l /dev/sda`

```
Disk /dev/sda: 223.58 GiB, 240065183744 bytes, 468877312 sectors
Disk model: SanDisk SSD PLUS
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 13AFDE80-C05F-4536-8EC8-A158544DF9E4

Device       Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048      4095      2048     1M BIOS boot
/dev/sda2     4096   4198399   4194304     2G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  4198400 468875263 464676864 221.6G Linux filesystem
```

[fdisk -l /dev/sda](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kb4m.jpg)

output of:
`df -Th`

```
Filesystem                        Type     Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                             tmpfs    586M  3.4M  582M   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv ext4      98G   23G   71G  24% /
tmpfs                             tmpfs    2.9G     0  2.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                             tmpfs    5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
/dev/sdb1                         ext4     458G   55G  380G  13% /hitachi
/dev/sda2                         ext4     2.0G  253M  1.6G  14% /boot
overlay                           overlay   98G   23G   71G  24% /var/lib/docker/...
overlay                           overlay   98G   23G   71G  24% /var/lib/docker/...
overlay                           overlay   98G   23G   71G  24% /var/lib/docker/...
overlay                           overlay   98G   23G   71G  24% /var/lib/docker/...
tmpfs                             tmpfs    586M  4.0K  586M   1% /run/user/1000
```

[df -Th](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BaoG.jpg)

output of:
`vgdisplay`

```
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               ubuntu-vg
  System ID
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  3
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                1
  Open LV               1
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               221.57 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              56723
  Alloc PE / Size       56723 / 221.57 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0
  VG UUID               NgPC4F-Fbmw-yXsi-M5hy-Fbnx-f0Bv-13Kwo9
```

[vgdisplay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NTXL.jpg)

Thank you

Comment: What is the output of `vgs` and `lvs`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear you have a 98GB filesystem sitting on a 221GB LVM device. If this is the case all you need to do is extend the filesystem.

`resize2fs /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv`

Good luck

If you have any important data on this device please create a backup first.